# HTML 5 Canvas and QR Code

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, qr-code

I'm using this repository [qrcode](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) to generate QR codes

This is my Jquery

```
    $(".generatetext").click(function() {
        var x = document.getElementById("textdata").value;
        $('#output').qrcode(x);
    });
```

so this gets the input value of the user and generates the QR code on click on a button.
but every time I click "Generate Button" it generates a new QR code in a new line, doesn't replace the existing one.

```
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>-> on first click
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>-> on second click
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>-> on third click
```

[DEMO](http://www.textalter.com/qr-code-generator/) -<- generate 2 or 3 qr codes

it creates a list of QR codes. how do I solve this problem?
I want just one QR code to be shown every time I click on Generate button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check working solution below.

```js
$(".generatetext").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $("#textdata").val();
    $('#output').html('').qrcode(x);
});
```

```css
#output{border:1px solid #eee;min-height:200px;width:200px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.qrcode/1.0/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary generatetext">Generate QR Code</button>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textdata" placeholder="Enter text for QR Code" />
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="output" class="text-center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check below mentioned solution.

```
$(".generatetext").click(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("textdata").value;
     $('#output').html('').qrcode(x);
});
```

Let me know if it not works

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong, Please check working example in my answer.

Comment: @gumireddy: Glad to help you out from this hurdle, Let me know if you need other help

Comment: need help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552919/ondrop-event-create-new-element?noredirect=1#comment78065773_45552919