# ondrop event - create new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using sortable feature of jquery.

[image: on drag]

please check the image,

If i drag an item from Base Data and drop it in Filters, i need a text box to be created on Texfields column.

i dont want to pre populate all the Filters and Textfields.

so if i can drag and drop a item from base data that i require to Filters. A text box should be create for each drop..

help please!!!

my code 
HTML

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                 <h4>Base Data</h4>
                 <ol class="simple_with_no_drop vertical">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                 </ol>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                 <h4>Filters</h4>
                 <ol class="simple_with_no_drag vertical" style="border: 1px solid #444;"> <br>             
                 </ol>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <h4>Textfields</h4>
                 <ol class="" style="border: 1px solid #444;"><br>
                 </ol>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                 <h4>Hierarchy</h4>
                 <ol class="simple_with_drop vertical">
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                 </ol>
              </div>
```

CSS

```
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
    cursor: move !important;
}
.dragged {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 2000;
}
ol.vertical {
    margin: 0 0 9px 0;
    min-height: 10px;
}
ol.vertical li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: #0088cc;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
ol.vertical li.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

JS/Jquery

```
$(function () {
     $("ol.simple_with_drop").sortable({
       group: 'no-drop',

       onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
           // Duplicate items of the no drop area
           if (!container.options.drop)
               $item.clone().insertAfter($item);
           _super($item, container);
       }
     });
     $("ol.simple_with_no_drop").sortable({
       group: 'no-drop',
       drop: false
     });
     $("ol.simple_with_no_drag").sortable({
       group: 'no-drop',
       drag: false
     });
     });
```

Comment: @abagshaw i have updated the code .. please check

Comment: @shyam-shingadiya need help with this

Comment: @gumireddy: Which jQuery you have used for sortable..? You have used `jquery-ui` or anything plugin?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya i have used this https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below mentioned solution. It will help you.

```js
!function(t,e,i,o){function s(t,e){var i=Math.max(0,t[0]-e[0],e[0]-t[1]),o=Math.max(0,t[2]-e[1],e[1]-t[3]);return i+o}function n(e,i,o,s){var n=e.length,r=s?"offset":"position";for(o=o||0;n--;){var a=e[n].el?e[n].el:t(e[n]),h=a[r]();h.left+=parseInt(a.css("margin-left"),10),h.top+=parseInt(a.css("margin-top"),10),i[n]=[h.left-o,h.left+a.outerWidth()+o,h.top-o,h.top+a.outerHeight()+o]}}function r(t,e){var i=e.offset();return{left:t.left-i.left,top:t.top-i.top}}function a(t,e,i){e=[e.left,e.top],i=i&&[i.left,i.top];for(var o,n=t.length,r=[];n--;)o=t[n],r[n]=[n,s(o,e),i&&s(o,i)];return r=r.sort(function(t,e){return e[1]-t[1]||e[2]-t[2]||e[0]-t[0]})}function h(e){this.options=t.extend({},u,e),this.containers=[],this.options.rootGroup||(this.scrollProxy=t.proxy(this.scroll,this),this.dragProxy=t.proxy(this.drag,this),this.dropProxy=t.proxy(this.drop,this),this.placeholder=t(this.options.placeholder),e.isValidTarget||(this.options.isValidTarget=o))}function l(e,i){this.el=e,this.options=t.extend({},c,i),this.group=h.get(this.options),this.rootGroup=this.options.rootGroup||this.group,this.handle=this.rootGroup.options.handle||this.rootGroup.options.itemSelector;var o=this.rootGroup.options.itemPath;this.target=o?this.el.find(o):this.el,this.target.on(g.start,this.handle,t.proxy(this.dragInit,this)),this.options.drop&&this.group.containers.push(this)}var c={drag:!0,drop:!0,exclude:"",nested:!0,vertical:!0},u={afterMove:function(t,e,i){},containerPath:"",containerSelector:"ol, ul",distance:0,delay:0,handle:"",itemPath:"",itemSelector:"li",bodyClass:"dragging",draggedClass:"dragged",isValidTarget:function(t,e){return!0},onCancel:function(t,e,i,o){},onDrag:function(t,e,i,o){t.css(e)},onDragStart:function(e,i,o,s){e.css({height:e.outerHeight(),width:e.outerWidth()}),e.addClass(i.group.options.draggedClass),t("body").addClass(i.group.options.bodyClass)},onDrop:function(e,i,o,s){e.removeClass(i.group.options.draggedClass).removeAttr("style"),t("body").removeClass(i.group.options.bodyClass)},onMousedown:function(t,e,i){return i.target.nodeName.match(/^(input|select|textarea)$/i)?void 0:(i.preventDefault(),!0)},placeholderClass:"placeholder",placeholder:'<li class="placeholder"></li>',pullPlaceholder:!0,serialize:function(e,i,o){var s=t.extend({},e.data());return o?[i]:(i[0]&&(s.children=i),delete s.subContainers,delete s.sortable,s)},tolerance:0},p={},f=0,d={left:0,top:0,bottom:0,right:0},g={start:"touchstart.sortable mousedown.sortable",drop:"touchend.sortable touchcancel.sortable mouseup.sortable",drag:"touchmove.sortable mousemove.sortable",scroll:"scroll.sortable"},m="subContainers";h.get=function(t){return p[t.group]||(t.group===o&&(t.group=f++),p[t.group]=new h(t)),p[t.group]},h.prototype={dragInit:function(e,i){this.$document=t(i.el[0].ownerDocument);var o=t(e.target).closest(this.options.itemSelector);if(o.length){if(this.item=o,this.itemContainer=i,this.item.is(this.options.exclude)||!this.options.onMousedown(this.item,u.onMousedown,e))return;this.setPointer(e),this.toggleListeners("on"),this.setupDelayTimer(),this.dragInitDone=!0}},drag:function(t){if(!this.dragging){if(!this.distanceMet(t)||!this.delayMet)return;this.options.onDragStart(this.item,this.itemContainer,u.onDragStart,t),this.item.before(this.placeholder),this.dragging=!0}this.setPointer(t),this.options.onDrag(this.item,r(this.pointer,this.item.offsetParent()),u.onDrag,t);var e=this.getPointer(t),i=this.sameResultBox,s=this.options.tolerance;(!i||i.top-s>e.top||i.bottom+s<e.top||i.left-s>e.left||i.right+s<e.left)&&(this.searchValidTarget()||(this.placeholder.detach(),this.lastAppendedItem=o))},drop:function(t){this.toggleListeners("off"),this.dragInitDone=!1,this.dragging&&(this.placeholder.closest("html")[0]?this.placeholder.before(this.item).detach():this.options.onCancel(this.item,this.itemContainer,u.onCancel,t),this.options.onDrop(this.item,this.getContainer(this.item),u.onDrop,t),this.clearDimensions(),this.clearOffsetParent(),this.lastAppendedItem=this.sameResultBox=o,this.dragging=!1)},searchValidTarget:function(t,e){t||(t=this.relativePointer||this.pointer,e=this.lastRelativePointer||this.lastPointer);for(var i=a(this.getContainerDimensions(),t,e),s=i.length;s--;){var n=i[s][0],h=i[s][1];if(!h||this.options.pullPlaceholder){var l=this.containers[n];if(!l.disabled){if(!this.$getOffsetParent()){var c=l.getItemOffsetParent();t=r(t,c),e=r(e,c)}if(l.searchValidTarget(t,e))return!0}}}this.sameResultBox&&(this.sameResultBox=o)},movePlaceholder:function(t,e,i,o){var s=this.lastAppendedItem;(o||!s||s[0]!==e[0])&&(e[i](this.placeholder),this.lastAppendedItem=e,this.sameResultBox=o,this.options.afterMove(this.placeholder,t,e))},getContainerDimensions:function(){return this.containerDimensions||n(this.containers,this.containerDimensions=[],this.options.tolerance,!this.$getOffsetParent()),this.containerDimensions},getContainer:function(t){return t.closest(this.options.containerSelector).data(i)},$getOffsetParent:function(){if(this.offsetParent===o){var t=this.containers.length-1,e=this.containers[t].getItemOffsetParent();if(!this.options.rootGroup)for(;t--;)if(e[0]!=this.containers[t].getItemOffsetParent()[0]){e=!1;break}this.offsetParent=e}return this.offsetParent},setPointer:function(t){var e=this.getPointer(t);if(this.$getOffsetParent()){var i=r(e,this.$getOffsetParent());this.lastRelativePointer=this.relativePointer,this.relativePointer=i}this.lastPointer=this.pointer,this.pointer=e},distanceMet:function(t){var e=this.getPointer(t);return Math.max(Math.abs(this.pointer.left-e.left),Math.abs(this.pointer.top-e.top))>=this.options.distance},getPointer:function(t){var e=t.originalEvent||t.originalEvent.touches&&t.originalEvent.touches[0];return{left:t.pageX||e.pageX,top:t.pageY||e.pageY}},setupDelayTimer:function(){var t=this;this.delayMet=!this.options.delay,this.delayMet||(clearTimeout(this._mouseDelayTimer),this._mouseDelayTimer=setTimeout(function(){t.delayMet=!0},this.options.delay))},scroll:function(t){this.clearDimensions(),this.clearOffsetParent()},toggleListeners:function(e){var i=this,o=["drag","drop","scroll"];t.each(o,function(t,o){i.$document[e](g[o],i[o+"Proxy"])})},clearOffsetParent:function(){this.offsetParent=o},clearDimensions:function(){this.traverse(function(t){t._clearDimensions()})},traverse:function(t){t(this);for(var e=this.containers.length;e--;)this.containers[e].traverse(t)},_clearDimensions:function(){this.containerDimensions=o},_destroy:function(){p[this.options.group]=o}},l.prototype={dragInit:function(t){var e=this.rootGroup;!this.disabled&&!e.dragInitDone&&this.options.drag&&this.isValidDrag(t)&&e.dragInit(t,this)},isValidDrag:function(t){return 1==t.which||"touchstart"==t.type&&1==t.originalEvent.touches.length},searchValidTarget:function(t,e){var i=a(this.getItemDimensions(),t,e),o=i.length,s=this.rootGroup,n=!s.options.isValidTarget||s.options.isValidTarget(s.item,this);if(!o&&n)return s.movePlaceholder(this,this.target,"append"),!0;for(;o--;){var r=i[o][0],h=i[o][1];if(!h&&this.hasChildGroup(r)){var l=this.getContainerGroup(r).searchValidTarget(t,e);if(l)return!0}else if(n)return this.movePlaceholder(r,t),!0}},movePlaceholder:function(e,i){var o=t(this.items[e]),s=this.itemDimensions[e],n="after",r=o.outerWidth(),a=o.outerHeight(),h=o.offset(),l={left:h.left,right:h.left+r,top:h.top,bottom:h.top+a};if(this.options.vertical){var c=(s[2]+s[3])/2,u=i.top<=c;u?(n="before",l.bottom-=a/2):l.top+=a/2}else{var p=(s[0]+s[1])/2,f=i.left<=p;f?(n="before",l.right-=r/2):l.left+=r/2}this.hasChildGroup(e)&&(l=d),this.rootGroup.movePlaceholder(this,o,n,l)},getItemDimensions:function(){return this.itemDimensions||(this.items=this.$getChildren(this.el,"item").filter(":not(."+this.group.options.placeholderClass+", ."+this.group.options.draggedClass+")").get(),n(this.items,this.itemDimensions=[],this.options.tolerance)),this.itemDimensions},getItemOffsetParent:function(){var t,e=this.el;return t="relative"===e.css("position")||"absolute"===e.css("position")||"fixed"===e.css("position")?e:e.offsetParent()},hasChildGroup:function(t){return this.options.nested&&this.getContainerGroup(t)},getContainerGroup:function(e){var s=t.data(this.items[e],m);if(s===o){var n=this.$getChildren(this.items[e],"container");if(s=!1,n[0]){var r=t.extend({},this.options,{rootGroup:this.rootGroup,group:f++});s=n[i](r).data(i).group}t.data(this.items[e],m,s)}return s},$getChildren:function(e,i){var o=this.rootGroup.options,s=o[i+"Path"],n=o[i+"Selector"];return e=t(e),s&&(e=e.find(s)),e.children(n)},_serialize:function(e,i){var o=this,s=i?"item":"container",n=this.$getChildren(e,s).not(this.options.exclude).map(function(){return o._serialize(t(this),!i)}).get();return this.rootGroup.options.serialize(e,n,i)},traverse:function(e){t.each(this.items||[],function(i){var o=t.data(this,m);o&&o.traverse(e)}),e(this)},_clearDimensions:function(){this.itemDimensions=o},_destroy:function(){var e=this;this.target.off(g.start,this.handle),this.el.removeData(i),this.options.drop&&(this.group.containers=t.grep(this.group.containers,function(t){return t!=e})),t.each(this.items||[],function(){t.removeData(this,m)})}};var v={enable:function(){this.traverse(function(t){t.disabled=!1})},disable:function(){this.traverse(function(t){t.disabled=!0})},serialize:function(){return this._serialize(this.el,!0)},refresh:function(){this.traverse(function(t){t._clearDimensions()})},destroy:function(){this.traverse(function(t){t._destroy()})}};t.extend(l.prototype,v),t.fn[i]=function(e){var s=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);return this.map(function(){var n=t(this),r=n.data(i);return r&&v[e]?v[e].apply(r,s)||this:(r||e!==o&&"object"!=typeof e||n.data(i,new l(n,e)),this)})}}(jQuery,window,"sortable");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ol.simple_with_drop").sortable({
        group: 'no-drop',
        drop: false,
        drag: false,
        onDrop: function($item, container, _super) {
            $('.selectedFilters').append('<li><input type="text" id="' + $item.data('id') + '" placeholder="' + $item.html() + '" /></li>');
            $item.find('ol.dropdown-menu').sortable('enable');
            _super($item, container);
        }
    });
    $("ol.simple_with_no_drop").sortable({
        group: 'no-drop',
        drop: false
    });
    $("ol.simple_with_no_drag").sortable({
        group: 'no-drop',
        drag: false
    });
});
```

```css
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
    cursor: move !important;
}
.dragged {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 2000;
}
ol.vertical {
    margin: 0 0 9px 0;
    min-height: 10px;
}
ol.vertical li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: #0088cc;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
ol.vertical li.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
ol.selectedFilters {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Base Data</h4>
            <ol class="simple_with_no_drop vertical">
                <li data-id="filter1">Base Item 1</li>
                <li data-id="filter2">Base Item 2</li>
                <li data-id="filter3">Base Item 3</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Filters</h4>
            <ol id="filters" class="simple_with_no_drag vertical" style="border: 1px solid #444;"> <br>             
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Textfields</h4>
            <ol class="selectedFilters" style="border: 1px solid #444;"><br>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Hierarchy</h4>
            <ol class="simple_with_drop vertical">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it not works or you need any other requirement.

Comment: it worked perfect! have got one more thing. - after i drop an item into filters. i need to delete the item, so if i hover on a dropped item inside filters, an (X) icon pops up and on click of it, both the dropped item and the generated text field should be deleted... is it possible>?

Comment: Yes, Everything is possible, But need to invest some time on it.

Comment: help me with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589952/jquery-ui-sortable-sort-li-value-to-text-field