# JQuery UI Sortable, Sort li value to text field

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

[image]

Im using JQuery UI, for sortable feature.

i'm able to drag from base data list to hierarchy and sortable is working.

But if i drag a li item from base data list to text box inside Measure formula the value should be copied.

please check the example that i have typed.

Thanks

JS

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        remove: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }).disableSelection();
```

HTML

```
    <ul id="sortable1" class="sortable1 connectedSortable list-unstyled table1">
    <li class="base-li-item">Example 1</li>
    <li class="base-li-item">Example 2</li>
    <li class="base-li-item">Example 3</li>
    <li class="base-li-item">Example 4</li>
    <li class="base-li-item">Example 5</li>
    <li class="base-li-item">Example 6</li>
    <li class="base-li-item">Example 7</li>
    </ul>

<input id="basedatadrag" type="text" style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: @Shyam Shingadiya hope you can help me on this...

Comment: Can you please share your working snippet or fiddle.?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below mentioned solution. It will help you.

```js
$(function() {
    $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        revert: false,
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var formula = [];
            ui.item.attr('draggable', "false").removeClass('ui-state-highlight').addClass('ui-state-default');
            $('#sortable2 li').each(function(index) {
                formula.push('{' + $(this).html() + '}');
            });
            $('#basedatadrag').val(formula.join('+'));
        }
    });

    $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        revert: true,
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var formula = [];
            ui.item.attr('draggable', "false").removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-highlight');
            $('#sortable2 li').each(function(index) {
                formula.push('{' + $(this).html() + '}');
            });
            $('#basedatadrag').val(formula.join('+'));
        }
    }).draggable(false);
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; padding: 5px; width: 143px;}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
        
        <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
            Base Data
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
            Hierarchy
        </ul>
        <br style="clear:both"> <br style="clear:both">
        <input id="basedatadrag" type="text" style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: Hi Shyam, sorry, please check my question again, this one is different. this is jqueryUI

Comment: Hey Shyam, help me with this, this the last project and last screen with my present company.. out of disappointment im not able to do anything.. help me with this one.. please

Comment: @gumireddy : Can you please share me your working code.? So I can update and get it done.

Comment: @gumireddy : I just updated my code(answer) with `jQuery UI`, It will help you.

Comment: Hey Shyam it works perfect!! thanks!! but my requirement is slightly different. now when i drag a list item from base data to hierarchy the list item data is getting copied to the text box! but what im looking for is... (if i drag a list item from base data directly to input box, i should get the value of list item inside text box.. just drag and drop to text box..)

Comment: I hope this will help you to reach your requirement, one more thing for you it's last project but for me today was the last day in my current company..

Comment: oh i saw that you are starting up something.. i was going though your twitter http://www.shingadiya.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151670/discussion-between-gumireddy-and-shyam-shingadiya).